# Origin evil.example in Request Header

Tags: web-services, google-chrome, header, same-origin-policy, referer

I am trying to send form data to a webservice but below "Request Header" in the "Network" of the Chrome DOM I got the origin `evil.example` and referer "localhost:8080".

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:nb-NO,nb;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nn;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2,en;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:91
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;
Host:office.insoft.net:9091
Origin:http://evil.example/
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2230.0 Safari/537.36
```

I want to change to another origin and "localhost:8080" would be the best origin.

How do I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 131):

The overwrite of the header origin is caused by `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` chrome extension.

[Link to the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Try disabling this extension in order to solve your problem.

Comment: Which extension are you referring to? A name or link would be helpful.

Comment: Looks like this is it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi Name is "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" as above. Apologies, it didn't look like the name of the extension.

Comment: Worst name for an addon.

Comment: Isn't evil.com kind of disconcerting? Is this benign or evil?

Comment: how the CORS issue is bypassed by this extension by simply adding **Origin**: evil.com/?

Comment: This extension brings trouble when you want to allow CORS credentials: "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'."

Comment: It could be from any extension that copies from the chrome developer examples.
see included link
[chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#examples)

Comment: https://github.com/vitvad/Access-Control-Allow-Origin/issues/45 I must admit that scared me out too, lol.

Answer (score 0):

To create a jupyter_notebook_config.py file if it is not there, , you can use the following command line from ~/.jupyter:

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Uncomment this

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
```