# AJAX Post request error: "can't be blank", [validation: :required] When sending JSON object in POST body

Tags: ajax, ecto, elixir, elixir-poison

I'm getting this error when a request hits my router at `OPTIONS "/products"`

**error**

```
14:45:33.433 [error] #PID<0.339.0> running Api.Router terminated
Server: 192.168.20.3:4000 (http)
Request: OPTIONS /products
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {:brand, {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}}
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:383: Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:259: anonymous fn/3 in Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:260: Poison.Encoder.List."-encode/3-lists^foldr/2-1-"/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:260: Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:227: anonymous fn/4 in Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:228: Poison.Encoder.Map."-encode/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:228: Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:227: anonymous fn/4 in Poison.Encoder.Map.encode/3
```

**Image showing the error caught on the frontend that occurred during the network request:**

[image]

Judging by the image above it looks like the product JSON object does get sent so for some reason it isn't correctly mapping the http post body to the elixir changeset.

**log of conn:**

```
Interactive Elixir (1.4.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> %{}
%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{},
 before_send: [], body_params: %{},
 cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, halted: false,
 host: "192.168.20.3", method: "OPTIONS", owner: #PID<0.339.0>, params: %{},
 path_info: ["products"], path_params: %{}, peer: {{192, 168, 20, 3}, 63793},
 port: 4000,
 private: %{plug_route: #Function<1.14347947/1 in Api.Router.do_match/4>},
 query_params: %{}, query_string: "", remote_ip: {192, 168, 20, 3},
 req_cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies},
 req_headers: [{"host", "192.168.20.3:4000"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"},
  {"access-control-request-method", "POST"}, {"origin", "http://evil.com/"},
  {"user-agent",
   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/
537.36"},
  {"access-control-request-headers", "content-type,x-requested-with"},
  {"accept", "*/*"}, {"referer", "http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui"},
  {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch"},
  {"accept-language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"}], request_path: "/products",
 resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{},
 resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}],
 scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: nil, state: :unset,
 status: nil}
%Api.Product{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "products">, brand: nil,
 description: nil, id: nil, image: nil, name: nil, numberOfVotes: nil,
 rating: nil}
```

**router.ex**

```
defmodule Api.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  if Mix.env == :dev do
    use Plug.Debugger
  end
  plug :match
  plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json],
                   pass:  ["application/json"],
                   json_decoder: Poison
  plug :dispatch

  get "/favicon.ico" do
    # Api.Repo.getCategories(conn)
  end

  get "/categories/" do
    Api.Repo.getCategories(conn)
  end

  options "/categories/" do
    Api.Repo.getCategories(conn)
  end

  post "/products" do
    Api.Repo.insertProduct(conn, conn.body_params)
  end

  options "/products" do
    IO.puts inspect conn.body_params
    Api.Repo.insertProduct(conn, conn.body_params)
  end

  get "/products" do
    Api.Repo.insertProduct(conn, conn.body_params)
  end
end
```

**In repo.ex**

```
  def insertProduct(conn, product) do
    IO.inspect(conn)
    changeset = Api.Product.changeset(%Api.Product{}, product)
    errors = changeset.errors
    valid = changeset.valid?
    case insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, product} ->
        conn
          |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
          |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
              successs: "success"
          }))
      {:error, changeset} ->

        conn
          |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
          |> send_resp(500, Poison.encode!(%{
              failure: changeset
          }))
    end
  end
```

**product.ex**

```
defmodule Api.Product do
  use Ecto.Schema

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :brand, :description, :image, :rating, :numberOfVotes]}
  schema "products" do
    field :name, :string
    field :brand, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :image, :string
    field :rating, :integer
    field :numberOfVotes, :integer
  end

  def changeset(product, params \\ %{}) do
    product
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:name, :brand, :description, :image, :rating, :numberOfVotes])
    |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:name, :description, :brand])
  end
end
```

By the way - [origin is evil.com because of a browser plugin I use to enable CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27380605/3935156)

Comment: The first line of your `insertProduct` function body is `IO.puts conn`. The problem is that `conn` is a struct, and `IO.puts/2` takes a string argument. You can switch this to `IO.inspect` if you are trying to debug something other than a string or char data.

Comment: @stevelove Awesome thank you that helped a lot. Have updated the question.

Comment: The answer is there in the error: `expected params to be a map, got: %Api.Product{...}`. Probably here: `lib/api/product.ex:16`. You seem to be calling one of Ecto's `cast` functions with a struct (i.e. `%Api.Product{}`) when the function is expecting you to pass a map, i.e. `%{}`.

Comment: @stevelove Yeah thanks. Will make it expect a `%Api.Product{...}`

Comment: I think the problem is in repo.ex, you are creating a Product struct out of `params` and sending that to `Api.Product.changeset`. Just send `params` straight in.

Comment: @stevelove yes that fixed that error thanks! Onto the next one. Working on it myself but updated the question anyway since I got further ahead thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Some javascript global constants used in react native to allow network requests to show in the chrome developer console:

```
GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest
```

Seem to also mess with the network requests themselves. Once I got rid of that code it inserted the `POST`ed product into the database.

Thanks for the comments which got me most of the way.